# For which $a$ does this system have one solution, infinite solutions, or no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system of linear equations:

\begin{cases} x+y+az=1 \\ x+ay+z=1 \\ ax+y+z=1 \end{cases}

For which $a$ does the system have:

1. no solution
2. one solution
3. an infinite number of solutions?

So first I reduced the matrix to echelon form

\begin{pmatrix}{cc|cc}
1&1&a&1\\1&a&1&1\\a&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}

and after raw operations got to 
\begin{pmatrix}{cc|c}
1&1&a&1\\0&a-1&1-a&0\\0&0&-a^2-a+2&1-a\end{pmatrix}

Therefore $-a^2-a+2=1-a$ so when $a=1, a=-1$ there are infinitely many solutions, but when is there one solution?

Comment: You should really have $(-a^{2} - a + 2)z = 1 - a$.  Check again for $a = -1$.  You get $2z = 2$, or $z = 1$.  Then, the second line gives the equation $(a - 1)y + (1- a)z = 0$, and since $z = 1$ when $a = -1$, we get $-2y + 2 = 0$ or $y = 1$.  Then you can solve for $x$.  So $a = -1$ gives a unique solution.  For which $a$ are there no solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a = 1$, the system reduces to $x + y + z = 1$, and it has more unknowns than equation, hence infinite solutions. If $a \neq 1$, then subtract the second from the first equation:
$(a-1)(z-y) = 0$. So: $z-y = 0$, and $y = z$. Similarly subtract the third from the second equation: $(a-1)(y-x) = 0$. So $y - x  = 0$, and $x = y$. Thus: $x = y = z$, and $x + x + ax = 1$. So: $(a+2)x = 1$. So if $a = -2$, system has no solutions, and if $a \neq -2$, it has unique solution: $x = y = z = \dfrac{1}{a+2}$